# Submit-PnPSearchQuery - Does this search inside documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We have several documents in our online SharePoint site. We need to write a Powershell script that will return a list of all documents with a specific word in it. Is this command supposed to return content this way?

Example: Submit-PnPSearchQuery "my Name" where any document that includes that phrase in the body of it should be returned in the result rows.

Answer (score 0):

It search document body and if you want to return more information, please use the cmdlet below:

`(Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "your querey").ResultRows|%{$_["Title"],$_["Path"],$_["Author"]}`

Here is a test in my end.
[image]